# OL3 event priority

Tags: javascript, events, openlayers

I have three events in OL3 registered as follows:

```
map.on('click',function(){..});

lineStringdraw.on('drawstart', function(e) {...});

map.on('pointermove', function(e){...});
```

the two first events are problematic when I start drawing. which one is triggered first can affect the rest of the code. Sometimes the third one is also triggered between the two first events. Somehow it seems to be random!!!!!
I don't know how or in what order or priority they are handled.

**Edit**

I need the pointermove as I am measuring distance between pointer and the lines and points for snapping to them. It is always running so that as soon as I click to start drawing, if it is close to a line or node, snap the starting point. Then the drawstart should be triggered so that I can check some conditions to be met. If so, then I add some info to the feature as properties. I also need the click event while I am drawing a line to snap to the closest lines and points to keep topology of the network correct.

Comment: I'd expect the `pointermove` event to trigger when the pointer is moved... I guess this is also the case while drawing as still.. the pointer is moving over the map. You'll probably want to deactivate handlers that shouldn't be active while drawing etc.

Comment: I need it as I am measuring distance between pointer and the lines and points for snapping to them. It is always running so that as soon as I click to start drawing if it is close to a line or node, snap the starting point. then the drawstart should be triggered so that I can change the first point to the closest point. I also need the click event while I am drawing a line to snap to the closest lines and points to keep topology of the network correct.

Comment: I can't really follow your description, maybe you'd like to put a working example together to make it easier for others helping here. Something that may be helpful is this example: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/examples/snap.html There is a snapping interaction in ol3 that you may use. It also states "The snap interaction must be added after the Modify and Draw interactions in order for its map browser event handlers to be fired first. Its handlers are responsible of doing the snapping."

Comment: I was trying to write my own piece of code for snapping, while there is a snapping module in OL3. Thanks @bentrm! it helped me a lot but to be fair it is not directly answering the question. I dont know if I should accept it as the correct answer or not!!!

Comment: It's only a comment anyway so it can't be accepted.